# How do I spell the address correctly in router to access the method?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Link : https://example.com/infonews?id=43

```
$router->get('/infonews', [NewsController::class, 'infonews']);
```

---

```
public static function infonews(Router $router)
{

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        error_log($_GET['id']);
    }

    $router->renderView('news/infonews', []);
}
```

Comment: check this documentation of laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: If you have a route with `$router->get(..)`, you don't manually need to check if it the method is GET in the controller since only GET requests to that URL will be matched.